# Error while bootstrapping cloudify nodecellar example on localhost using virtualenv

Tags: cloudify

executing bootstrap validation
Invalid input:

```
inputs.yaml. inputs must represent a dictionary.
Valid values can either be a path to a YAML file, a string formatted as YAML or a string formatted as key1=value1;key2=value2
```

How to solve this problem??

Comment: using cloudify 3.2.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are a lot of missing details in your question, I'll try to explain what could be the answer:

1. You didn't give the right path to the input.yaml file.

The path could be relative to your working directory, or a full path, but either way it must lead to the file.

2. Your input file is not formatted correctly.

An input.yaml file should include a dictionary of keys and values as in: `image: 'redhat_santiago'`. Tabs are not allowed, only spaces. All keys should be aligned to the same column.

Please try to check the above, in the future it would be better if you add the input file and the command you are using.

Best,
Jonathan

Comment: the file name in the bootstrap command was wrong. it should have been input.yaml.template